# Não fazer download ao exportar para Xls utilizando PHP

Tags: php

Sempre uso um script para exportar dados para xls com PHP.
Me serviu muito, mas, neste caso, preciso apenas gerar o xls e anexar no e-mail.

Passei boa parte de manhã tentando fazer que o script apenas gere a planilha, sem forçar o download, mas, se eu tiro o "Content-Disposition: attachment", dá erro na página.

Segue o script:

```html
<?php
 include("php/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"); 
 
 // Trazendo as informações da tabela: 
 $header = "";
 $dados  = "";
  
 $header .= utf8_decode('Serviço'. "\t");
 $header .= utf8_decode('Projeto nº'. "\t");
 $header .= utf8_decode('Cliente'. "\t");
 $header .= utf8_decode('Processo'. "\t");
 $header .= utf8_decode('Vencimento'. "\t");

 // Select dos processos para fazer o lembrete
 $sql_2 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT ps.data_vencimento_limite, ps.id_processo, IFNULL(NULL, ps.num_processo), ps.descricao, c.nome_razao FROM tb_processos_servicos ps LEFT JOIN tb_processos AS p ON (ps.id_processo = p.id_processo) LEFT JOIN tb_agenda AS c ON (p.cliente = c.id) WHERE ps.data_vencimento_limite <> '0000-00-00' AND ps.data_vencimento_limite <= '$data_atual_db' ORDER BY ps.data_vencimento_limite DESC") or die(mysqli_error($config));
 
 if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_2) <= 0){
  echo "";
 }else{
  while($r_sql_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_2)){
   $vencimento_limite = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r_sql_2[0]));
   $id_processo       = $r_sql_2[1];
   $num_processo      = $r_sql_2[2];
   $descricao_sel     = utf8_decode($r_sql_2[3]);
   $cliente_sel       = utf8_decode($r_sql_2[4]); 

   // Insere a linha 
   $line = '';
   $value = '"' ."$descricao_sel". '"' . "\t";
   $value .= '"' ."$id_processo". '"' . "\t"; 
   $value .= '"' ."$cliente_sel". '"' . "\t"; 
   if(empty($num_processo)){
    $value .= '""' . "\t";
   }else{
    $value .= '"' ."'$num_processo". '"' . "\t";
   }
   $value .= '"' ."$vencimento_limite". '"' . "\t";
   $line .= strtr($value,"","") ;    

   // O trim retira os espaços encontrados no começo e no final de cada linha encontrada. 
   $dados .= trim($line)."\n";

   // Substituindo todas as quebras de linha ao final de cada registro, que por padrão seria \r por uma valor em branco, para que a formatao fique legível
   $dados = str_replace("\r","",$dados);

   // Caso não encontre nenhum registro, mostra esta mensagem. 
   if ($dados== "") {
    $dados = "\n Nenhum registro encontrado!\n"; 
   }     
  }

  // O trim retira os espaços encontrados no começo e no final de cada linha encontrada. 
  $dados .= trim($line)."\n";

  // Substituindo todas as quebras de linha ao final de cada registro, que por padrão seria \r por uma valor em branco, para que a formatao fique legível
  $dados = str_replace("\r","",$dados);   

  // Cabeçalhos e instruções para geração e download do arquivo:
  header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");

  // Este cabeçalho abaixo, indica que o arquivo deve ser gerado para download.
    // Se eu tirar ele salva o arquivo na pasta, mas dá erro na página
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome_arquivo");

  // No cache, ou seja, não guarda cache, pois é gerado dinamicamente 
  header("Pragma: no-cache");

  // Não expira 
  header("Expires: 0");

  // E aqui geramos o arquivo com os dados mencionados acima! 
  print "$header\n$dados"; 

  file_put_contents("anexos/".$nome_arquivo,$dados); 

    //Aqui será enviado o e-mail.  
  
 }

 mysqli_close($config);
?>
```

Não sei é possível apenas gerar o xls com esse script, mas ele é tão prático que vou fazer uma última tentativa.

Neste caso ele salva na pasta "anexos", mas abre a caixa do navegador para fazer download.

Comment: Onde está `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome_arquivo");` troque para `header("Content-Disposition: inline");`

Comment: Com essa alteração imprimiu tudo na tela, ao invés de gerar o xls.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro esta no direcionamento do conteudo, se voce experimentar trocar para simplesmente gerar o arquivo sem mexer no header da pagina, e tambem adicionando o caminho relativo devera resolver.

Repare que no seu codigo print esta indo para o buffer atual e nao para um arquivo de destino, talvez isso esteja influenciando